# How To Remove Automatic Datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

i have datagridview like below :

```
| FIleName      | Amount     | Description |
--------------------------------------------
| Test001       | 1000       |             |
| Test002       | 1000       |             |
| Test003       | 1000       |             |
```

i try to automatic execute rows in datagridview the use thread.sleep.  while i execute button StartAuthorization, i want execute the data Rows one by one and remove rows if rows after executed;
i tried this code :

```
private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Thread.Sleep(10000);
 while (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
  RunAtomationRun(); // method to execute rows in datagridview
  int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
  DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];
  DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex);
 }
}
```

but not works ? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there are actually rows selected before using `selectedrowindex`. But how does your function select the row to work on?

You should really pass the row to the function and remove it when the function succeeds:

```
private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Thread.Sleep(10000);
 while (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
  DataGridViewRow currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
  RunAtomationRun(currentRow); // method to execute rows in datagridview
  DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(currentRow);
 }
}
```

Or let the function remove the row on success, I suppose it already knows wich one it is working on:

```
private void RunAtomationRun()
{
 // Find row to work on
 DataGridViewRow currentRow = ...

 // Work on row...

 // Delete Row on success
 DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(currentRow);
}
```

Both variants should fix your problem.

Comment: i use this code to selected cells      :  "  if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
         {
             int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
             DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];
             dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex);
         } "

Comment: @MuhammadIbnuSaefullah Yes and if there are no selected Cells this does nothing wich is probably what you see. Do you want it do do nothing if there are no selected rows? If you want it to execute one row every 10 seconds then change your code, see above.